# Deleting from Firebase with Document ID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase to store and retrieve Data. I am able to successfully save data to Firestore but nothing seems to happen when I delete the user from the Firestore.

Initially when the user creates an object (Package)

```
let newPackage = PackageObject(context: self.context)
            
//Set Package properties
newPackage.trackingNumber = trackingNumberLabel.text!
newPackage.packageDescription = packageDescriptionLabel.text
newPackage.packageCarrier = carrierNameLabel.text!
newPackage.circleIndicatorColor = StringLiteral.redColor
newPackage.currentDescription =  StringLiteral.defaultDescription
newPackage.carrierLogoName = carrierNameLabel.text!
newPackage.id = randomString(length: 20)

let homeInstance = HomeViewController() // New HomeViewController Instance
homeInstance.addPackageObject(newObject: newPackage) // Add tracking Number
homeInstance.requestData(newTrackingNumber: newPackage)
```

Core Data Class

```
//MARK: - CoreData and Related Functions
extension HomeViewController
{
    
    func addPackageObject(newObject: PackageObject)
    {
        CoreDataManager.sharedManager.insertPackageObject(newObject: newObject) //Add Object to Core Data
        addTrackingNumberToFirebase(newObject: newObject) // Add Object to Firebase Database
    }
    
    func deletePackageObject(deleteObject: PackageObject)
    {
        deletePackageFromFirebase(newObject: deleteObject)
        CoreDataManager.sharedManager.delete(person: deleteObject) //Delete Package Object from Core Data
      
    }
    
    func loadPackageObject() -> [PackageObject]
    {
        return CoreDataManager.sharedManager.loadTrackingNumber()
    }
    

    func saveTrackingNumber()
    {
        CoreDataManager.sharedManager.save()
    }
    

}
```

Firebase Helper

```
extension HomeViewController
{
    func addTrackingNumberToFirebase(newObject: PackageObject)
    {
        let dict = [
            "tracking_Number": newObject.trackingNumber!,
                    "id": newObject.id!,
                    "package_Description": newObject.packageDescription!,
                    "package_Carrier": newObject.packageCarrier!,
                    "circle_Indicator_Color": newObject.circleIndicatorColor!,
                    "current_Description": newObject.currentDescription!,
                    "carrier_LogoName": newObject.carrierLogoName!
        ]
        
       // db.collection("tracking_Numbers").addDocument(data: dict) //Add without Custom ID
        db.collection("tracking_Numbers").document(newObject.id!).setData(dict) //Add Document with ID
    }
    
    func deletePackageFromFirebase(newObject: PackageObject)
    {
        
        }
    
}
```

For some reason my data is not being deleted from Firebase

Here is my Firebase rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore 
{
  match /databases/{database}/documents 
  {
    match /{document=**} 
    {
      allow read, write: if true;
    
    }
// Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
// match /users/{userId} {
//       allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
//       allow create: if request.auth != null;
//     }

  }
}
```

Is there something I am missing

Comment: There is no code in your `deletePackageFromFirebase` function.

Comment: Agree with @Paulw11, it's not deleting because there is no code to delete it. Also, it's not clear why you're unwrapping a non-optional object property `newObject.id!` and lastly it's not clear why you're storing duplicate data in CoreData and Firebase. Firebase has offline persistence so that's probably duplicating everything and unnecessary (?)